# OWASP AppSec Israel Conference 2013

Tags: discussion, conference

The [annual OWASP AppSec Israel Conference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Israel_2013) will take place this year on Tuesday, October 1, 2013, between 9:00 and 17:00, at the IDC in Herzliya (Israel).

**OWASP Israel is the largest conference in the region for Application Security, and regularly draws over 300 participants – don’t miss it!**

The Conference will include lecture tracks, and also a sponsors display area for vendors of products relevant to Application Security.
The [list of talks are really fascinating](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Israel_2013_Presentations), with some of the “regular” speakers from Ernst&Young, AppSec Labs, Checkmarx and others, and some new speakers. Topics will range from high-level insights to demoing brand new technical research.

The conference is free to attend, as always.

---

If you are indigenous to that region, or just happen to be in the area, I hope you will make it to the conference - and I would love to meet up!

**So, is anybody here going to be at this conference?**

Also - if you are at the conference and a Sec.SE user - I just might have a special gift for you (assuming the package makes it here in time)... ;-)
So be sure to find me...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you missed it, or were there and were not able to catch all the sessions, most of these have been recorded. The videos are now online at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTmd7ahBXAU&list=SPA4gj-PiNukdr7SY4XKoF4xhb0XZYw-WI .

You can find the [session abstracts and speaker bios on the conference page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Israel_2013_Presentations).